# Bash - whitespace appears in front

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell

In Bash script I have this lines:

```
FULL_NAME1="$LAST_NAME$FIRST_NAME"
echo $FULL_NAME1

FULL_NAME="%$LAST_NAME$FIRST_NAME%"
echo $FULL_NAME
```

First one prints with no space in front:

```
Smith John
```

Second prints:

```
%  Smith John%
```

Both first and last print with no spaces:

```
FIRST_NAME=`sudo -u user psql -t -d database -c "select first_name from contact where id = '$CONTACT_ID';"`
echo $FIRST_NAME

LAST_NAME=`sudo -u user psql -t -d database -c "select last_name from contact where id = '$CONTACT_ID';"`
echo $LAST_NAME
```

Trying to use `| xargs` for above but it erases both first and last.

Why is this happening and how do I go about deleting this white space in front?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Quote  your parameter expansions: `echo "$FULL_NAME1"`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when bash expands the $FULL_NAME1 , it is just

```
echo    Smith  John
```

try instead:

```
echo "$FULL_NAME1"
```